# how to subtract two dates and times to get difference

Tags: php, datetime

i have to sent an email when a user register email contain a link that is become invalid after six hours
what i m doing when email is sent i update the db with field emailSentDate of type "datetime"
now i got the curent date and time and has made to the same formate as it is in db now i want to find that both these dates and time have differenc of 6 hours or not so that i can make link invalid but i donot know how to do this

my code is look like this i m using hardcoded value for db just for example

```
$current_date_time=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$current=explode(" ",$current_date_time);
$current_date=$current[0];
$current_time=$current[1];
$db_date_time="2010-07-30 13:11:50";
$db=explode(" ",$db_date_time);
$db_date=$db[0];
$db_time=$db[1];
```

i do not know how to proceed plz help

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subtract+dates+php

Answer (score 19):

```
<?php
//$now = new DateTime(); // current date/time
$now = new DateTime("2010-07-28 01:11:50");
$ref = new DateTime("2010-07-30 05:56:40");
$diff = $now->diff($ref);
printf('%d days, %d hours, %d minutes', $diff->d, $diff->h, $diff->i);
```

prints `2 days, 4 hours, 44 minutes`

see http://docs.php.net/datetime.diff

edit: But you could also shift the problem more to the database side, e.g. by storing the expiration date/time in the table and then do a query like
`... WHERE key='7gedufgweufg' AND expires<Now()`
Many rdbms have reasonable/good support for date/time arithmetic.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work with all versions of PHP. I don't have a `diff()` method...

Comment: That's right. The manual says `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)` which was released in June 2009 ;-)

Comment: I know, crazy :-/ I should change my hosting provider, I guess... I have 5.2.x

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is convert both of your dates to [Unix epoch times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_Epoch), that is, the equivalent number of seconds since midnight on the 31st of December 1969. From that you can easily deduce the amount of time elapsed between the two dates. To do this you can either use [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) or [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

All the best.

Answer (score 2):

$hoursDiff = ( time() - strtotime("2010-07-30 13:11:50") )/(60 * 60);

Comment: you r subtracting current date of time from saved date of time and result will be in hours is it?

Comment: hey it is creating problem for same day suppose i have to find difference of the same day it results in negative value

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather work with a timestamp: Save the value which is returned by "time()" as "savedTime" to your database (that's a timestamp in seconds). Subtract that number from "time()" when you check for your six hours.

`if ((time() - savedTime) > 6 * 3600)
  // more than 6h ago`

or

`"SELECT FROM table WHERE savedTime < " . (time() - 6 * 3600)`

Comment: not sure it answers the question, but it's the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution to your problem -> [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-2-dates-using-php)

Comment: $hoursDiff = ( time() - strtotime("2010-07-30 13:11:50") )/(60 * 60);
this code give negative result can u help me y this is happening