# "Days between" should return 1 when going over a day boundary, even within 24 hours

Tags: php, datetime

I have the current function:

```
function getDaysBetween($start, $end) {
    $start = strtotime($start);
    $end = strtotime($end);
    $dateDiff = abs($end- $start);
    $daysBetween = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    return $daysBetween;
}
```

The function above does return the days between.

So, for example, August 3 at 3.00 AM minus August 2 at 11PM gives 0.

In this case I would like it to return 1, since these are different days. How can I achieve that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371011/how-to-subtract-two-dates-and-times-to-get-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$start = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);
```

use

```
$start = strtotime('00:00:00', strtotime($start));
$end = strtotime('00:00:00', strtotime($end));
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the time from your **$start** and **$end**, simply pass the date. e.g. 03/08/2011 instead of 03/08/2011:03:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDaysBetween($start, $end) {
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $start->setTime(0,0,0);
    $end->setTime(0,0,0);
    $dateDiff = abs($end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp());
    $daysBetween = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    return $daysBetween;
}
```