# how to subtract one date to another using php

Tags: php

I want to subtract one date to another using php and display result in the days - hours - min - sec format. How i do this using php . I tried this using time stamp but it does not give proper values. please give suggestion

For ex : from date 2012-04-27 19:30:56  to date  2012-04-27 19:37:56

i used this code

```
if(strtotime($history['datetimestamp']) > strtotime($lasttime)) {

                 $totalelapsed1 = (strtotime($history['datetimestamp'])-strtotime($lasttime)); 




                     if($totalelapsed1 > 60 ) {
                         $sec = $totalelapsed1%60;
                         $min = round($totalelapsed1/60 , 0);

                         $minute = $min + $minute;
                         $second = $sec + $second;

                        // echo $min. " min " .$sec." sec";

                     } else {
                         //echo "0 min " . $totalelapsed1." sec";

                         $minute = 0 + $minute;
                         $second = $totalelapsed1 + $second;

                    }



                } else {
                     $minute = 0 + $minute;
                     $second = 0 + $second;
                    // echo "0 min 0 sec";
                }
```

Comment: [Check the answered post in this thread][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [how to subtract two dates and times to get difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371011/how-to-subtract-two-dates-and-times-to-get-difference/3371061#3371061) by [VolkerK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833/volkerk):

> You have to use like this:-
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> //$now = new DateTime(); // current date/time
> $now = new DateTime("2010-07-28 01:11:50");
> $ref = new DateTime("2010-07-30 05:56:40");
> $diff = $now->diff($ref);
> printf('%d days, %d hours, %d minutes', $diff->d, $diff->h, $diff->i);
> prints 2 days, 4 hours, 44 minutes
> ```
>
> see http://docs.php.net/datetime.diff
>
> edit: But you could also shift the problem more to the database side, e.g. by storing the expiration date/time in the table and then do a query like
>   ... `WHERE key='7gedufgweufg' AND expires<Now()`
>   Many rdbms have reasonable/good support for date/time arithmetic.

Link Url:- [how to subtract two dates and times to get difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371011/how-to-subtract-two-dates-and-times-to-get-difference)

http://www.webpronews.com/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php-2005-11

Comment: Much faster than doing this manually and just what I needed - thanks!

Comment: If you change the year/month this will only show "2 days, 4 hours, 44 minutes" it doesn't count months

Comment: Nevermind... there is a parameter that I didn't saw. `->days` that show all days in the interval

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use DateTime and DateInterval objects.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2007-03-24");
$date2 = new DateTime("2009-06-26");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "days difference ".$interval->d." days ";
```

read more php [DateTime::diff manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DateTime:diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Examples are provided on that page.

Answer (score 0):

This script resolve my issue

```
$date1 = date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime($date1));

$date2 = date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime($lasttime));

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  $months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));  $days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));  $minuts  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60);  $seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minuts\n, %d seconds\n", $years, $months, $days, $hours, $minuts, $seconds);
```