# How To Validate X Days Before D-Day?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Let's say I have given date like this :

```
$Christmas = '2012-12-25';
$Today = date('Y-m-d');
```

I want to create an `if` statement like this :

```
if ($Today != 7 days before $Christmas) {
  echo 'Christmas still to far away';
}else ($Today == 7 days before $Christmas) {
  echo 'Christmas will be here within less than a week!';
}
```

How to create validation date such like that? thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have no idea how to subtract 2 dates....

Comment: @RobertHanson: Have a look at the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371011/how-to-subtract-two-dates-and-times-to-get-difference

Comment: A simple google search for "*difference between two dates php*" would have answered the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for you.. This will at least give you a basic idea on how to do it.

*Simple things like this dont need any complication... working out larger dates with years, months, etc would need a more complex solution and usually a pre-made library works best.*

Do note, in my example the number of days will be float. So outputting to the user would need some rounding.

The idea is to convert the time to a UNIX timestamp, subtract it and divide it by the number of seconds in a day 84,600. Presto! The Number of days!

```
<?php

$today = time();
$xmas = strtotime("12/25/2012");
// You can also use mktime():
// $xmas = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, 2012)
$diff = ($xmas-$today);
$days = ($diff/84600);

if($days === 7)
{
    echo '1 week til xmas';
}
if($days > 0 && $days < 7)
{
    echo 'Less than 1 week to xmas';
}
if($days === 0)
{
    echo 'Today is xmas';
}
if($days < 0)
{
    echo 'xmas is long gone...';
}

?>
```